# how to align text in textview Object in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to presnt the text that was back from the server on the UI. i succedd to get the data but for some reason my date (textViewDate) is not begin with the other lines such as place (textViewPlace) and time (textViewTime).
how can i align it in a proper way?

this is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativlayoutGcmMessage"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is the message"
        android:textSize="20sp"



        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUser"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewloc" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBtn"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separatorDown"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button android:text="Join"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonJoin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#606060"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutBtn"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUser"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewUser">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/separatorUp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/separatorDown"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User ,"
        android:id="@+id/textViewUser"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separatorUp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="When:"
        android:id="@+id/textViewWhen"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/separatorDown"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewWhen"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUser"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewUser" />

    <Button android:text="Deny"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDeny"
        android:layout_width="361dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#606060"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Between:"
        android:id="@+id/textViewbtwn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:id="@+id/textViewtime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewbtwn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewbtwn" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location:"
        android:id="@+id/textViewloc"

        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewWhen"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="place"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewtime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewtime"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is how its look like on my device:
[image]

Comment: add it onlt to the textViewDate or for all the 3 textViews?

Comment: still i got the same result.

Comment: try removing marginLeft 40dp from textViewDate textView

Comment: use  yourdateString.trim() and than set it in textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this layoute Like this:

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
    android:textSize="20sp"        
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewWhen"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUser"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewUser" />
```

in This code has Remove This Line..

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
```

I think its Work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Table layout

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location:"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="place"
               />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="When:"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                 />
            </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Between:"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                 />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Also remove the margin property from DATE text.